# Send request to page with windows-1251 encoding from python

Tags: python, utf-8, flask, python-requests, encode

i need get a page source (html) and convert him to uft8, because i want find some text in this page( like, if 'my_same_text' in page_source: then...). This page contains russian text (сyrillic symbols), and this tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
```

I use flask, and request python lib.
i send request
source = requests.get('url/')

```
if 'сyrillic symbols' in source.text: ...
```

and i can`t find my text, this is due to the encoding
how i can convert text to utf8? i try .encode() .decode() but it did not help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's create a page with an `windows-1251` charset given in `meta` tag and some Russian nonsense text. I saved it in Sublime Text as a windows-1251 file, for sure.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Привет, мир!</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

You can use [a little trick](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content) in the `requests` library:

> If you change the encoding, Requests will use the new value of r.encoding whenever you call r.text.

So it goes like that:

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: result = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:1234/1251.html')

In [3]: result.encoding = 'windows-1251'

In [4]: u'Привет' in result.text
Out[4]: True
```

Voila!

If it doesn't work for you, there's a slightly uglier approach.

You should take a look at what encoding do the web-server is sending you.

It may be that the encoding of the response is actually `cp1252` (also known as `ISO-8859-1`), or whatever else, but neither `utf8` nor `cp1251`. It may differ and depends on a web-server!

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: result = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:1234/1251.html')

In [3]: result.encoding
Out[3]: 'ISO-8859-1'
```

So we should recode it accordingly.

```
In [4]: u'Привет'.encode('cp1251').decode('cp1252') in result.text
Out[4]: True
```

But that just looks ugly to me (also, I suck at encodings and it's not really the best solution at all). I'd go with a re-setting the encoding using `requests` itself.

Answer (score 2):

[As documented](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content), `requests` automatically decode `response.text` to unicode, so you must either look for a unicode string:

```
if u'cyrillic symbols' in source.text:
    # ...
```

or encode `response.text` in the appropriate encoding:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# (....)
if 'cyrillic symbols' in source.text.encode("utf-8"):
    # ...
```

The first solution being much simpler and lighter.