# Cyrillic encoding in request

Tags: character-encoding, python-requests

I already read the following: [Send request to page with windows-1251 encoding from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365356/send-request-to-page-with-windows-1251-encoding-from-python)

Yet I cannot print a correct string. I have tried nearly every combination of u''.join, encode and decode I could think about...

```
import requests
url = 'http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe'
payload = {'CL': '1', 's': 'foo', 'l1':'1'}

r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
# ????????? print(u''.join(r.text))
```

I'd be very glad to get a solution and an explanation, because I really do not get it!

Comment: is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: Python 2, more precisely, the anaconda 2 package